# Windows Azure Cloud Service Rekey SSL

Tags: azure, ssl

I received a notice that I must rekey my SSL from SHA-1 to SHA-2. I have a cloud service running on Azure and my SSL already exists. How do I get this rekeyed SSL into my cloud service? I am using Visual Studio Online to deploy the package.

I see this docs, however, I am not uploading my package manually:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/#step1

Comment: What's the problem? I assume the rekeyed cert has a new fingerprint. You upload a new cert, then change the service configuration and redeploy the service. Same as when your cert is about to expire and you renew it.

Comment: If I use Visual Studio Online to deploy, how do I upload a new cert? Do I have to completely remove my deployment, then follow the steps from that KB I used?

Comment: You could use the Management Portal to upload the cert.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the option is at the bottom of Cloud Services > Certificates > Upload.